# Keep Win 10 MacBook Pro asleep when lid closed

Tags: windows-10, sleep, boot-camp

My current MacBook Pro (Late 2016 model) as well as my previous MacBook Pro (Mid 2010 model) both exhibit the same behavior when suspended.

If they are awoken while the lid is closed, usually through the external mouse being bumped, they will not return to sleep mode until the lid is opened. Instead they will stay awake and get hotter and hotter as heat is trapped. This is quite annoying and I believe dangerous for the machines. And I am unable to solve this thus far.

I believe this is because I also have an external monitor plugged in. I believe it is the ill conceived "Closed Laptop Mode" where a user, for reasons I'll never understand, wishes to use their laptop with an external monitor but not the built-in monitor.

Is there a way, any way, to get this laptop to stay asleep when closed, to NEVER activate "Closed Laptop Mode" or to get it to return to sleep if awoken while closed.

Things I have done thus far:

1. I have set the external USB Mouse (Logitech M510 wireless with universal adapter dongle thing) to not be able to wake the computer from sleep. This did not help.
2. Disabled Wake Timers when plugged in and on battery
3. Set Lid and Power buttons to all be set to sleep
4. Googled like crazy

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you've already set the mouse to not wake the computer. If it is **not** the mouse waking the computer, you can find out what is by using the "powercfg -lastwake" command in the Command Prompt. More info can be found at the source I used: https://www.howtogeek.com/122954/how-to-prevent-your-computer-from-waking-up-accidentally/

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We prefer questions and answers to be self-contained. While this link may fully answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Links can become invalid if the linked page changes.